# If element contains child elements run function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a carousel on my site, and if there are no elements my jquery seems to crash.

My HTML output without elements is...

```
<section class="gallery-viewport-twobedroomapartment viewer">
     <ul>
     </ul>
     <a id="simplePrevious"><img alt="Left Arrow" src="_includes/images/larr.png"></a>
     <a id="simpleNext"><img alt="Right Arrow" src="_includes/images/rarr.png"></a>
</section>
```

And my jQuery is...

```
$('.gallery-viewport-twobedroomapartment').carousel('#simplePrevious', '#simpleNext');
```

Is it possible to say if UL contains LI then run the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($('.gallery-viewport-twobedroomapartment ul > li').length > 0) {
   $('.gallery-viewport-twobedroomapartment').carousel('#simplePrevious', '#simpleNext');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To know if there are any elements in a jQuery collection use `length`.

```
if ($(elements).length) {
  // there are elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var liCount = $('ul li').length;

if (liCount > 0) {
  $('.gallery-viewport-twobedroomapartment').carousel('#simplePrevious', '#simpleNext');
}
```

Boom!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.children()` and `length`:

```
if ($(".gallery-viewport-twobedroomapartment").children("ul").children("li").length > 1)
    $('.gallery-viewport-twobedroomapartment').carousel('#simplePrevious', '#simpleNext');
```